# CBCentralManagerDelegate functions in separate singleton file, but they are not running (Swift)

Tags: swift, core-bluetooth

In my app, I need to access Core Bluetooth across multiple view controllers, so I moved all Central Manager functions into a separate singleton class called CentralManagerClass (I can access functions and variables with CentralManagerClass.shared.variableName).

However, when I run my code, none of these Central Manager functions like

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber){}
```

or

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {}
```

are running anymore. However, these functions DID run when I put them in an extension ViewController: CBCentralManagerDelegate.

I set up 
`CentralManagerClass.shared.centralManager=CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)` in all of my view controllers, but do I need to call these CBCentralManagerDelegate functions a different way?

***EDIT***

This is what ended up working for me:

1. Getting rid of the **CBCentralManagerDelegates in the view controllers**
2. Getting rid of the `CentralManagerClass.shared.centralManager=CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)` or **Central Manager instances** from all of the view controllers
3. Turning the **singleton** into the CBCentralManagerDelegate
4. Using notifications to make actions happen in the view controllers out of the singleton file

Comment: If you now have a singleton then each view controller should not assign an instance of `CBCentralManager`. Your singletons’s initialiser should create that, once, when it is initialised.

Comment: Also, your view controllers can't be your singleton's `CBCentralManager`'s `delegate` - The singleton should be the delegate.  You will need to use some other method; either a protocol/delegation from the singleton or `Notification` to let the view controller's know about bluetooth events

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks! Getting rid of the CBCentralManagerDelegates and CBCentralManager instances from all of the view controllers, turning the singleton into the CBCentralManagerDelegate, and using notifications worked!